# grails - strange behaviour after data binding

Tags: grails

it is very common to use domainClass.properties = params to bind all incoming request params to a domain class object. i do not understand why this assignment automatically updates the domain object. e.g.

```
def update = {
  def book = Book.get(1)
  book.properties = params
  book.discard()
}
```

the params assignment updates the domain object. discard method has no effect. can anyone help me?

Comment: When you say "automatically updates", do you mean that the domain object is persisted? Just trying to clarify what's going on.

Comment: I think we need some more context here. What is the data connection and how is it set? Doing book.properties = params does nothing else than just setting values of the object's properties to what is in params. It does not save the object.

Comment: yeah, "automatically updates" means the the doamin object get persisted. the data connectin is a simple hsqldb. i implemented a very simple exmaple to clearify the problem. imagine we this controller action:

def book = Book.get(1)
book.properties = params
[book : book]

futhermore the book domain class has a beforeUpdate closure to journalize every update.

def beforeUpdate = {
   log.error "update book"
}

the book has only one prop -> String title. Everytime the prop is changed through the data binding, before update is called. so that means the book obj. get saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discard() method will not reset the book instance, only prevent that it will be saved automatically by Grails. To reset the book instance you need to reload it, e.g. using Book.get(1).

And book.properties = params will simply try to assign the elements in the params map to properties of Book where the property name is the same as the map entry key. I believe this is standard Groovy functionality, and not Grails specific.

Comment: thanks for the answer. my problem is that through data binding the obj get persisted when some properties of the domain obj. has been changed. see my comment before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the answer by Ruben has been selected as correct. @hitt5 the behavior is as expected but yes it's different and you will find the reason here:
http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/
See the section 'Now you're saving when I don't want you to?!' in particular.